# JavaScript установка таймера с приостановкой

Tags: javascript

У меня есть `setInterval` с функциией внутри. Вот упрощенный код с кратким описанием желаемого релультата:

```
    setInterval(function() 
    {

    if(text.includes("pls, stop"))
    {
        // тут нужно остановить таймер, подождать минуту, и снова возобновить его
    }

    //к примеру,
    alert('hi');

    }, 100);
```

Вкратце - таймер проверяет наличие определенного текста в переменной `text`, и, в случае если он в ней есть, задерживается на 60 секунд. Важно, чтобы страница не зависала в момент ожидания. Через минуту таймер должен продолжить работу. Есть простой и удобный способ это реализовать?

Comment: Реализовать подобные манипуляции в JS легко, страница конечно подвисать не будет. Таймеры можно легко останавливать, перезапускать по несколько штук даже друг в друге.

Comment: Но не понятно, что конкретно Вы хотите достичь, какой алгоритм, последовательность всех действий Вам нужна. Например, `в случае если он в ней есть, задерживается` – а если нету? И что значит `остановить таймер, подождать минуту ` – ведь "ждать" это и есть работа таймера??

Comment: @AivanF спасибо за ответ, но не могли бы вы реализовать это на примере моего кода? Я мучаюсь уже 2 дня, пытаюсь использовать чужие примеры кода, но ничего не получается(

1) неважно, как ждать, главное описал ранее. 2) если нету текста, просто продолжить работу выполняя другой код.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1197891/%d0%a1%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b6%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5
Товарищи! Рядовому нужна ваща помощь!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, Вам нужно, чтобы таймер выполнялся то 10 раз в секунду, то раз в минуту. Тогда так:

```
// функция, которая будет выполняться
function fire() {
    if (text.includes("pls, stop")) {
        // подождать минуту
        setTimeout(fire, 60 * 1000);
    } else {
        // запустить "сразу"
        setTimeout(fire, 100);
    }

    // выполнить действие
    alert('hi');
}

// запустить
fire();
```

Таймеры в JavaScript'e не блокирующие, поэтому весь остальной код и вся страницу будут работать как прежде (можно сравнить их с отдельными потоками в других языках программирования). Советую также [почитать про различия `setTimeout` и `setInterval`](https://learn.javascript.ru/settimeout-setinterval).

Answer (score 2):

Таймера с какой-то логикой лучше делать с помощью setTimeout и рекурсии:

```js
let text = '';
const step = () => {
    console.log('Hi');
    const timeout = text.includes("pls, stop") ? 60000 : 100;
    setTimeout(step, timeout);
}

step();


// Проверка:
setTimeout(() => text = 'pls, stop', 1200);
```

Answer (score 1):

Если по какой-то причине хочется для таймера использовать именно `setInterval`, а не `setTimeout`, как в ответах выше, то можно сделать как-то так (хотя и тут без `setTimeout` не обошлось):

```js
let iter = 0;
let interval = setInterval(timer, 100)

function timer() {
  if (iter == 10) { // если выполняется условие,..
    clearInterval(interval); // ...то сбрасываем таймер...
    setTimeout(() => { // ...и устанавливаем его заново...
      interval = setInterval(timer, 100)
    }, 10000) // ...после необходимой паузы

  }
  console.log(iter++);
  if (iter > 20) { // для демонстрации достаточно и 20 итераций
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
};
```