# Скрипт таймера на джаваскрипте

Tags: javascript

Нужна помощь, а именно надо скрипт таймер при окончание автоматически кидался на другую страницу.

Comment: `setTimeout(() => location.href='google.com', 15000)`

Comment: а теперь сам таймер в студию пж)

Comment: Так, стоп, почему у вас в заголовке java, а в тегах javascript?

Comment: Опечатка , извините изменил уже

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://denis-creative.com/jstimer/ - первая ссылка в Яндексе. Добавь в условие при завершении отсчета необходимое действие.

UPD.
Не увидел комментарии сверху. Ссылка выше - визуальный таймер, если в нем нет необходимости - setTimeout(() => location.href='google.com', 15000) - это вполне рабочий метод.

Comment: Спасибо, мне не нужна визуалка, подскажите тут https://denis-creative.com/jstimer/  как поставить дату

Comment: Если вам не нужна визуалка, то вам нужен setTimeout

Comment: https://denis-creative.com/jstimer/ ---- вот такое мне нужна, я уже поставил на сайт код а как там ввести время я не понял

Comment: Переменная deadline отвечает за дату окончания таймера

Comment: Код напишите) мне надо на 11 ноября 2020 года

Comment: var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 11*24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

Comment: Спасибо , очень помогли) Искал это уже гдето неделью

Answer (score 1):

Код будет очень простой:

```
window.onload = timer;

const newSiteLink = 'your-site.com';
const timeout = 2000;

function timer() {
    setTimeout(() => location.href=newSiteLink , timeout);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если открываете везде, кроме Интернет Эксплорера, то ответ @vp_arth подходит. Если же важна работа и на IE, то замените стрелки на формат ES5:

```
setTimeout(function () { location.href = 'URL'; }, 15000);
```